# How can I generate a half second pause in TwiML?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to use Twilio's [<Say>](/docs/api/twiml/say) verb to pronounce a sequence of digits clearly. I'm finding it is hard to generate a natural (half-second) pause between each digit. How do I do this correctly?

The <Pause> xml command only takes integer values for seconds, so it's too long to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From here: [Link](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say)

- When saying numbers, '12345' will be spoken as "twelve thousand three
  hundred forty five." Whereas '1 2 3 4 5' will be spoken as "one two
  three four five."
- Punctuation such as commas and periods will be interpreted as **natural
  pauses** by the speech engine.
- If you want to insert a long pause try using the `<Pause>` verb. `<Pause>` should be placed outside `<Say>` tags, not nested inside them.

Comment: i used four periods to get the half second pause.

Comment: I guess that classifies a "natural pause" as 125 milliseconds. :P

Answer (score 5):

For less then one second pause:

```
<Say language="en-US" voice="alice">
Your verification code is 1,,,,2,,,,3,,,,4,,,,5
</Say>
```

You can increase and decrease the number of `commas` according to you convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This is tangentially related, but I figured people looking for something similar would end up on this question (like I did).

I wanted the `Say` verb to read a US phone number in a natural 3-3-4 cadence. Here is some C# that does just that. I'm sure you can figure out how to translate it to other languages:

```
private static string SayNaturalNumber(string digits)
{
    var newNumber = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            newNumber += digits[i];
        else
            newNumber += " " + digits[i];

        if (i == 2) //after third digit
            newNumber += ",,,,";

        if (i == 5) //after sixth digit
            newNumber += ",,,,";
    }
    return newNumber;
}
```