# Slow down Twilio's TwiML "Say" command for text-to-speech numbers

Tags: text-to-speech, twilio, twilio-twiml

I've created a Twilio application that involves using Twilio's TwimL `<Say>` command to read off a list of numbers that constitute an ID that the user has previously input (e.g., `3638194746219190` or something along those lines).  Since it's a long list of numbers, I have the application read back the list of numbers to confirm that the user has input them correctly.  Since it's dynamic, I can't pre-record it--it has to be with `<Say>`, but Twilio reads it back *way* too quickly.

I currently have the numbers played back with spaces and commas between them to slow them down, for example: `'3, 6, 3, 8, 1, 9, 4, 7, 4, 6, 2, 1, 9, 1, 9, 0'`, and that has helped a little bit, but it still reads the list back way too quickly.

Do you know how to force Twilio's `<Say>` command to slow down its text-to-speech playback even further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using periods, e.g. `1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.`

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple commas or periods and it'll increase the pause time. You may also consider adding longer breaks every X numbers so it has a more natural cadence to it.

```
3,,,6,,,3,,,8,,,,,,,1,,,9,,,4,,,7,,,,,,,4,,,6,,,2,,,1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `<Pause>` verb to pause execution for a number of seconds. The documentation is here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause

There's more information about generating pauses in TwiML at this question: [How can I generate a half second pause in TwiML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628933/how-can-i-generate-a-half-second-pause-in-twiml)

Comment: The `<Pause>` tag isn't what I'm looking for, since having 20 `<Say>` commands interlaced with 19 `<Pause>` commands to repeat back the ID would be inconvenient, not to say ugly within the code.  I'm looking for a way to slow down the `<Say>` in general, which could then extend to saying the words themselves as well.

Comment: @jdotjdot89 How is that ugly - you're not generating the TwiML programmatically? I'm pretty sure Twilio's parser won't see it and give you that 'oh really?' look.

Comment: @TimLytle I guess you're right; sometimes I used to use Jinja2 templating for the TwiML, but I could do it programmatically.  I guess it would work, but I don't like it conceptually.  But that's probably just me being stubborn.