# Customers cannot listen code properly due to speed of call is fast using Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using twilio api for voice message.

my code look like:

```
public bool SendVoiceCall(string FromNumber, string ToNumber)
        {

        string  URL = "http://twimlets.com/message?Message%5B0%5D=" + "hi, abc thanks for registration your code is : 7,2,4,9";
           URL = URL.Replace(" ", "%20");
           string AccountSid = "##########";
            string AuthToken = "##########";

            var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

            var options = new CallOptions();
            options.To = ToNumber;          
            options.Url = URL;
            options.From = FromNumber;
            options.Method = "GET";
            var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

}
```

I am having problem when call goes customer cannot listen message properly due to speed of the call message. So we need to have call in which customers can listen code properly with slow speaking words. Please advice me how can i make it slowly speaking code for my customers?

Regards,
Jatin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When saying numbers, '12345' will be spoken as "twelve thousand three
>   hundred forty-five." Whereas '1 2 3 4 5' will be spoken as "one two
>   three four five."
>
> **Punctuation such as commas and periods will be interpreted as natural
>   pauses by the speech engine.**
>
> is useful for saying dynamic text that would be difficult to
>   pre-record. In cases where the contents of  are static, you might
>   consider recording a live person saying the phrase and using the
>    verb instead.
>
> **If you want to insert a long pause, try using the  verb.
>    should be placed outside  tags, not nested inside them.**

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say

So I'd recommend using either more commas or try using the pause tag if possible

[Slow down Twilio's TwiML "Say" command for text-to-speech numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223060/slow-down-twilios-twiml-say-command-for-text-to-speech-numbers)

[Slow down Twilio's TwiML “Say” command for standard text on text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262678/slow-down-twilios-twiml-say-command-for-standard-text-on-text-to-speech)